# Font Awesome Icon in 127.0.0.1 vs localhost through Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, localhost, font-awesome

Font awesome icons in span tags by using localhost looks like this
[localhost in addressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7wMA.png)

While font awesome icons looks like this in 127.0.0.1
[127.0.0.1 in addressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2ATZ.png)

Take note that these site is created natively in html and css and transferred successfully to a wordpress theme in xampp.

My question is why is that font awesome icon and wordpress dashboard won't show up in localhost but shows up in 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have missed to call font-awesome by link tag in header.php.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Otherwise it's working fine for me as you can see in the snap
[image: localhost snap]

Comment: wordpress has this wp_enqueque function in the functions.php. i put all boostrap css there and fontawesome. Still got confused. why is it different from localhost and 127.0.0.1